# How to change versionCode with cordova?

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova

I upload my application in Google Play with the default versionCode and versionName, but i have a new code and i need to change this versionCode and versionName.

I searched for some solutions for this problem but any solution works for me

- config.xml

```
 android-versionCode="2" android-versionName="2.0"
```

- AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:versionCode="2" android:versionName="2.0"
```

- build.gradle

```
 defaultConfig {
     android:versionCode 2
     android:versionName "2.0"
  }
```

After configure this files i use the command

```
aapt dump badging myappPath.apk
```

It always returns versionCode="1" and versionName="1.0"

Please, help me.

Comment: Have you tried to change the version attribute in the config.xml like so `<widget .... version="2.0.0" >....</widget>`?

Comment: Yes but it still fails.

Comment: Appname/config.XML change the version code and version name. Once you did this one. From your terminal use this command "Cordova prepare".

Answer (score 39):

**edit your config.xml**, add "android-versionCode" and specify your versionCode manually:

```
widget id="com.xxxxx.yyyyyyyyyyy" android-versionCode="201018"
version="2.1.1"
```

Answer (score 30):

You may specify it in your config.xml file :

```
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova"
  version="0.0.1"
  android-versionCode="7"
  ios-CFBundleVersion="3.3.3">
```

Comment: This works great. It works even better if you set `android-versionCode=""`. This will tell cordova to create the version code from your version number. which is `major.minor.build`. For example, 1.2.33 becomes 10233. `(Major * 1000) + (minor * 100) + build`

Comment: This along @JohnPavek comment is the best answer.

Comment: Also see https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/#setting-the-version-code

Answer (score 25):

Cordova / PhoneGap / Ionic all accept arguments to the `build` command

```
# ionic
ionic build --release android -- --versionCode=3

# phonegap
phonegap build --release android -- --versionCode=3

# plain cordova
cordova build --release android -- --versionCode=3
```

You can see this command line arg being referenced in the source in `cordova/lib/build.js`:

```
if (options.argv.versionCode)
    ret.extraArgs.push('-PcdvVersionCode=' + options.argv.versionCode);
```

(Me: using Cordova version 6.1.1, ionic version 1.7.16)

Comment: None of the other methods worked, as of Cordova 6.5 and ionic 2.3...This is the only solution that has worked.

Comment: Works with cordova

Comment: Works with cordova 8.0.0, unlike fiddling with config.xml which did nothing.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution in this forum.

I used the next command

```
cordova build android -- --gradleArg=-PcdvVersionCode=2
```

Thanks Everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following step

```
AppFolder\config.xml change version
App Folder \platforms\android\res\xml\config.xml change version
App Folder \platforms\android\AndroidMainfest.xml change version
open the terminal and go to your folder like below => C:\Priya\App folder > "Cordova prepare"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following step

1. AppFolder\config.xml change version
2. App Folder \platforms\android\res\xml\config.xml  change version
3. App Folder \platforms\android\AndroidMainfest.xml change version
4. open the terminal and go to your folder like below =>   C:\Priya\App folder > "Cordova prepare"

Comment: No, it still fails.

Maybe it fails for the plugins?

Comment: What is your Cordova version

Comment: i'm using cordova 6.2.0